# Как вывести объекты из массива по значению ключа в JS?

Tags: javascript, json

Есть массив объектов:

```
[{"moduleId":2,"param":"ws_storage_login","value":"ndb"},{"moduleId":2,"param":"bpel_service_url","value":"http://1.112:9003"},{"moduleId":1,"param":"next_service_url","value":"http://localhost:8080"},
{"moduleId":0,"param":"work_mode","value":"AUTO"},{"moduleId":2,"param":"ws_storage_namespace_uri","value":"http://domainmode"}]
```

.
Как вывести только объекты, содержащие `"moduleId":2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На пример отфильтровать массив, 
[`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/uk/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const arr = [{
    "moduleId": 2,
    "param": "ws_storage_login",
    "value": "ndb"
  }, {
    "moduleId": 2,
    "param": "bpel_service_url",
    "value": "http://1.112:9003"
  }, {
    "moduleId": 1,
    "param": "next_service_url",
    "value": "http://localhost:8080"
  },
  {
    "moduleId": 0,
    "param": "work_mode",
    "value": "AUTO"
  }, {
    "moduleId": 2,
    "param": "ws_storage_namespace_uri",
    "value": "http://domainmode"
  }
];

console.log(arr.filter(el => el.moduleId === 2));
```